# Yum : How to retrieve option value from repositories configuration using python

Tags: python, yum

I have instance of `YumRepository` class. Is there a way to retrieve the option from configuration file of a repository, that I've added manually ?

Standard options are available as attributes of `YumRepository` instance e.g.
`rep.mirrorlist` - is the list of mirrors

Manually added option name in repositories config file is "notify=yes", how to retrieve it's value using `rep` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options: either hack RepoConf class before initializing yum, or use direct access to RawConfigParser object. The latter is quite simple:

```
foo = repo.cfg.get(repo.id, 'foo')
```

First option is more complicated, but more universal:

```
from yum import config, YumBase

config.RepoConf.foo = config.Option()

yum = YumBase()
for repo in yum.repos.listEnabled():
    print repo.id, repo.foo
```

Comment: Just found solution 
yum.config.getOption(rep.cfg, str(rep), 'notify', yum.config.BoolOption(True))